# For Machine.Specifications suites, is there a way to run code globally?

Tags: mspec

I'd like to execute startup/teardown code one time for all discovered specs when using Mspec.  Does it currently have any facility for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

`IAssemblyContext` is your friend. But it does that per assembly, not globally.